# Returning the innerHTML from a URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, httprequest

I'm trying to get the `innerHTML` element from a URL and I'm using the following code:

```
var getHTML = function (url, callback) {
    if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) return;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') {
            callback(this.responseXML);
        }
    }

    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.send();
}

getHTML('http://www.example.com/page', (response) => {
    var pageContents = document.querySelector(root).innerHTML;
})
```

When running the program, I get the following error:

```
if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) return;
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which page are you trying it with?

Comment: Remember, many websites disallow AJAX requests from external pages.

Comment: are you running this on node.js? because clearly node.js doesn't have a window variable but the browser version does.

Comment: why you don't use jQuery ajax instead of javascript XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Are you running this script in the browser? Do you use any module system?

Comment: @DakshMiglani yes I am. How might I go about solving that?

Comment: @Iaroslav no I'm running in VS Code through node.js

Comment: Nothing of your code will work in node js. For the requests, use the [request module](https://github.com/request/request), and for the parsing of the html use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Comment: @Bravewave [5 Ways to Make HTTP Requests in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)

Comment: @hosseinbadrnezhad You cannot provide code in jQuery unless asked by the Op

Comment: @Bravewave check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So You're using Node.js. Node.js doesn't have anything called as window, because window in the browser javascript context is the browser window.

Node.js doesn't have it because it runs on server, to make an http request through node.js you can use the following modules:

1. [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/node-fetch)
2. [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
3. [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

just do npm install [modulename] to install them. you can find the docs of them at npmjs.org